# Center of non-abelian group of order $17^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be group of order $17^4$. I have to find its center $Z(G)$ and $G/Z(G)$.

$|G|=17^4$.

Since $Z(G)$ is subgroup of $G$, the order of center divides the order of the group: $|Z(G)|=17^a$, where $a\leq4$.

$1^{\circ}$ $a=4$ $\Rightarrow |Z(G)|=|G|$. Since center of the group is Abelian, and the group is non-abelian, we have contradiction.

$2^{\circ}$ $a=3$ $\Rightarrow |G/Z(G)|=17$. This means that $G/Z(g)$ is cyclic, and then $G$ is Abelian. Contradiction.

What should I do with the cases $a=2$ and $a=1$?

And also, is this the right way to do this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What does it mean to "find its center"?

Comment: set isomorphic to center

Comment: You have done right so far, and I think that both cases $\;|Z(G)|=17,\,17^2\;$ can happen... and this can be somehow messy, I believe. You may want to read https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00461.pdf

Comment: can you help me finding the center of the group?

Comment: FOr the next time, instead of reposting please [edit] the existing post.

Comment: There are $10$ different nonabelian groups of order $17^4$. Which one is $G$?

Comment: This is not a valid problem because it does not have a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for all groups of order $17$ or $17^2$ there exist the examples of groups of order $17^4$, whose center is isomorphic to them.

For $C_{17} \times C_{17}$ it is $C_{17} \times (C_{17^2} \rtimes C_{17})$

For $C_{17^2}$ it is $C_{17^3} \rtimes C_{17}$

For $C_{17}$ it is $\langle x, y, z | x^{17^2} = e, x^{17} = y^{17} = z^{17}, x^{-1}yx =  y^n, x^{-1}zx =  z^n, y^{-1}zy =  z^n \rangle$ where $n^{17} \equiv 1 (\text{mod } {17}^2)$